# Apt update says a package can be upgraded but upgrade says the opposite

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa

From days I'm having this problem. When I run `sudo apt update` it says

`1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.`

and `sudo apt list --upgradable -a` output is

```
[NAME]/unknown 3.1.2-2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.1-19.1]
[NAME]/now 3.0.1-19.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 3.1.2-2.1]
```

but `sudo apt upgrade` says that there isn't anything to upgrade

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I don't even understand if it depends on Ubuntu version 17.04 64-bit or on package repository. One more strange thing is that `sudo apt-get update` doesn't show that I've 1 package to upgrade but `sudo apt-get upgrade` says

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  [NAME]
```

**Solution**:
After several attempts (all failed) I decided to reinstall Ubuntu and everything is fine now.

Comment: What happens for `apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Same as `apt upgrade`

Comment: Try to this command `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt update`. Is it helpful ?

Comment: @ali76 Nothing changed.

Comment: what is the output of this command : `ls /etc | grep motd` if you have a files with `motd.tail` name try to delete it `sudo rm /etc/motd.tail` then after `reboot` your problem should be solved.

Comment: @ali76 I had the file, deleted it, reboot the machine but nothing changed. I edited the question, watch out.

Comment: Please read all of this post instructions, it may be helpful https://serverfault.com/questions/262751/updates-in-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-10-04-server/262773#262773

Comment: @ali76 I've tried all answers in the post but they didn't work. I think that's because we've different versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @BetaRunner Please, see the thread here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388638/16920

Comment: As mentioned: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update` Logout. Login. Do you see: `do-release-upgrade`in MOTD? (or have you tried running do-release-upgrade?) -> If you find a resolution, please post as an answer...

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu server 18.04 for some weeks. It says "1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.". If I try this suggestion, then I can see: "libneon27/bionic-updates 0.30.2-3~ubuntu18.04.1 i386 [upgradable from: 0.30.2-2build1]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it". I tried with bshea's suggestion, but it didn't help.

Comment: @simo-r is this related to https://futurestud.io/tutorials/fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-keyexpired-the-following-signatures-were-invalid

Comment: I think people didn't answer because you just list [name] instead of the actual package name. Most likely, you can just install the packages by name: `sudo apt install [name]`